# Why using CSS display:grid of parent element shows a scroll bar for child element?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

When the content of the inner div is long and needs the scrollbar to be shown, the scroll bar is not showing unless I use display:grid on the parent (.container).

I know I can simply set height of inner-container to 100%.
But my question is why setting parent display to grid shows a scroll bar?
And is there any proper way to show a scrollbar without setting height of inner-container?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  height: 100px;
}

.inner-container {
  overflow-style: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What "other" display types have you tried? Have you set a specific height on either container element in the other display? Is the overflow hidden at all?

Comment: This "issue"  has nothing to do with grid. our code works as you have wrote it. use `overflow: auto` instead of `overflow: scroll`. `scroll` value will always show the scrollbar. The value `auto` will only show the scrollbar when an overflow occure. That however requires the child to be higher then the parents container which then requires a fixed/max-height for the parent.

Comment: @DavidThomas i tried all display options, only Grid shows a scrollbar.

Comment: display:flex will also give scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both `grid` and `flex` will give you scroll bar for a similar reason which is the default stretch alignment. `inner-container` will get stretched to its parent height due to that alignment so it's like having `height:100%` then you have your scrollbar because of the `overflow: scroll`

No other display can do the same because the stretch alignment exits only with flexbox and CSS grid.

If you disable it, it won't happen:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  height: 100px;
  align-items:start;
}

.inner-container {
  overflow-style: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```